# AngularJS: Filter array by type

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter the displayed elements of `$scope.drinks` array. The products is an array of objects, containing few elements with their own type: `food` or `drink`. I just want to filter the array if user clicks on the select option `food` or `drink`.

I was close to do it by myself, but experienced a lot of errors. I'm looking for most efficient way to do it.

Thanks for any help!

This is jsfiddle with whole app: https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/25/

**Edit:** I've already tried a solution with `ng-model="filterCategory"` and `filter : filterCategory`, but something really weird is happening. Even if the array is filtered, if I click on some element it add very other position! Just look at the gif:
[image]

New jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/27/

Comment: Post what you tried here. Tell precisely what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. "a lot of errors" is not precise enough. Also note that the official documentation for filter has an example doing almost exactly what you want: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: What's your expectation ?

Comment: @ManishSingh If the user clicks on e.g. 'food', only objects with type 'food' are shown.

Comment: You're filter conditions please?

Comment: @Aravind Everything (the whole app) is in the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/27/

Comment: That's great pat what are the errors your facing. If you can be specific it wil be easy to focus on it

Comment: @Aravind But you can see it on gif. After filtering the array with products, it seems to that array is only filtered by visibility, not in the real. Because if you can see, if I click on filtered 'food' product, instead of adding this 'food' into shop list, a DRINK is added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an ng-model="filterCategory" on the select and then use it with filter : filterCategory in the ng-repeat

```
 <div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="chooseCategory" ng-model="filterCategory">
    <option value="" disabled selected>- choose category -</option>
    <option value="drink">drink</option>
    <option value="food">food</option>
    <option value="">all positions</option>
  </select>
  <div class="itemListDiv">
    <ul class="list-group itemList">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-hide="product.isHidden" ng-repeat="(id, product) in drinks | filter : filterCategory" ng-click="addToShoppingList(product)">
        <strong>{{ product.name }}</strong> - {{ product.price | currency }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

ok i changed the value passed to function addToShoppingList and then in js:

```
$scope.addToShoppingList = function(product) {
    var index = $scope.drinks.indexOf(product);
    var itemToAdd = $scope.drinks[index];
    itemToAdd.quantity = 1;
    $scope.itemsToBuy.push(itemToAdd);
    $scope.drinks.splice(index, 1);
   };
```

Comment: I've already tried it, but received a weird result. Check out my post, Ive edited it.

Comment: have you added in js $scope.filterCategory = ''; ?

Comment: Nope, I didnt. Will do it now.

Comment: It doesnt change anything :(

Comment: i think it's related to id ...i'm investigating

Comment: Thank you a lot :)